# A counterexample of regular monic not closed under composition

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I am attempting Exercise 7J from Adámeck, Herrlich, and Strecker. Here is the setup. Let $A=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$ with the discrete topology, $B=A\cup\{0\}$ with the discrete topology, and $C=\mathbb{R}$ with the topology given by $\tau\cup\{U\setminus A:U\in\tau\}$, where $\tau$ is the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that both inclusions $A\to B$ and $B\to C$ are regular monic but not the composite $A\to B\to C$.

In $\textbf{Top}$, regular monics are exactly the homeomorphism onto the image, so we need to show the inclusion $A\to B$ is a homeomorphism onto the image (which is obvious), $B\to C$ homeomorphism onto the image, but not the composite $A\to B\to C$

I am stuck at the inclusion $B\to C$. It is continuous (obviously), but I don't see a way that it gives an open map. Take a singleton $\{b\}$ of $B$, how can we even express this as an arbitrary union + finite intersection of open subsets of $C$?

Further, the composite $A\to B\to C$ is clearly continuous (by discreteness of $A$), so it must be somehow not an open map, but this seems contradictory to what I did above: any subset $S\subseteq A$ is a union of singletons, but if we can express a singleton in $C$ as an arbitrary union + finite intersection of open subsets, then any singleton in $C$ is open, so the image of $S$ in $C$ is open, making the composite an open map

There must be something I understand wrongly. Any help is appreciate

Comment: $C$ is a familiar example (Munkres calls it the $A$-topology on $\Bbb R$, IIRC) to show that a Hausdorff space is not regular as we cannot separate $0$ from $A$ by disjoint open sets. So I'd expect that fact to play a rôle here, but I don't see how, as the sets $A$ and $B$ are both closed and discrete in $C$.

Comment: Embeddings are closed under composition...

Comment: Alex Kruckman (in a comment to my answer) says that the latest edition (2004) of the book says the consider the spaces to be in $\mathbf{FHaus}$, the full subcategory of functionally Hausdorff spaces. The example *does* seem to work there.

Answer (score 1):

The *set* $B=\{0\} \cup A$ is closed and discrete in $C$.

Discrete: all points of the form $\frac1n$ of $B$ are isolated (within $B$) as a subspace of $(\Bbb R,\tau)$ already and $C$ has a finer topology so this is preserved. $\{0\}$ is closed in $B$ too as $\{0\}=((-1,1) \setminus A) \cap B$ is open in $B$ as a subspace of $C$.

Closed: as $B$ is closed in $(\Bbb R, \tau)$ so also in the finer $C$.

Together this implies that the map $f(x)=x$ from the space $B$ (discrete topology) into $C$ is indeed a homeomorphism onto its image.

The composition from $x \to x$ from $A$ into $C$ is *also* a homeomorphism onto its image, so the statement that "regular monics in $\mathbf{Top}$ are embeddings" seems fishy, or the problem is flawed.

Comment: I did find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2658919/4280) problem showing regular monics to be embeddings. [This page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+monomorphism) also states that.

Comment: I first found this problem through [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712207/is-there-a-non-contrived-topological-example-where-regular-epics-are-not-close) post. The book is relatively old (at least 15 years old), so I don't think the problem can be flawed. And this is the only counterexample I can find through an intensive search, and this probably is the simplest such counterexample, so unable to figure this out is quite frustrating.

Comment: @Ray Age of the book says nothing, the amount of corrected reprints does. If regular monic = embedding, they are closed under composition. The referenced post is about $\mathbf{FHaus}$ where regular monics are closed embeddings, but that does not work either: if $e: A \to B$ is a closed embedding (so $e[A]$ closed in $B$) and $e': B \to C$ is also a closed embedding, then their composition is too (closed in closed is closed) ?

Comment: The exercise takes place in the category FHaus. The confusion is that in FHaus, regular monics are not closed embeddings, but rather embeddings such that the image is an intersection of zero sets.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Aha, that might make it a valid example for FHaus, as $A$ is not functionally closed in $C$, by the remark I made under the original question. Not for Top.

Comment: I agree. The book (at least the 2004 online edition) says to consider these spaces in tge category FHaus.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Aha, the problem is indeed asking in the category $\textbf{FHaus}$, but at the end it is just a full subcategory of $\textbf{Top}$ whose objects are functionally Hausdorff spaces. Then shouldn't it also work if we work in $\textbf{Top}$?

Comment: @Ray No, because a concrete function being a regular monic is dependent on what other spaces are in the category as well. So throwing spaces away can matter.